# Происхождение выражения "пятая колонна"

Tags: фразеология

Почему секретное сопротивление в стане врага называют пятой колонной? Почему "колонна" и почему именно "пятая"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С испанского: Quinta columna.
Принято считать, что это выражение из выступления по радио (осень, 1936) испанского генерала Эмилио Мола (1887—1937), который в годы гражданской войны в Испании (1936—1939) возглавлял наступление мятежников-франкистов на республиканский Мадрид. В нем он сказал, обращаясь с угрозами в адрес жителей республиканского Мадрида, что, помимо имеющихся в его распоряжении четырех армейских колонн, идущих на Мадрид, есть еще и пятая — в самом городе. Это тайные сторонники Франко, которые ударят республиканцам в спину, когда начнется решительное наступление на город.
По другой версии, эти слова Э. Мола произнес в своей штаб-квартире во время встречи с иностранными журналистами.
Есть и третья версия происхождения этого оборота: английский журналист лорд Сент-Освальд утверждал, что выражение «пятая колонна» впервые появилось в его телеграмме из Мадрида, посланной в редакцию британской газеты «Дейли телеграф» в сентябре 1936 г.
Но как бы то ни было, еще в годы гражданской войны в Испании понятие «пятая колонна» стало связываться с именем генерала Мола. Так, Долорес Ибаррури в статье «Защита Мадрида — защита Испании» (газ. «Мундо обреро» от 3 октября 1936 г.) писала: «Предатель Мола сказал, что он бросит на Мадрид «четыре колонны», но только «пятая» начнет наступление. (...) «Пятая колонна» находится внутри Мадрида, и в первую очередь надо разгромить ее». 
Популярности выражения способствовала пьеса Эрнеста Хемингуэя «Пятая колонна» (1938).

[Источник](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/2326/%D0%9F%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F)